# Demographic Prototype Differences?

Tags: prototype-theory

Are there any studies that have asked people to draw whatever first comes to mind for a particular word? If so, have any of those studies compared such prototypical drawings across genders, ages, or societies?
It's be interesting to see if there are significant average differences across demographics for prototypes of "mom", "dad", etc.